# Find the number of digits in the fractional part of a Decimal number in python

Tags: python, numbers, decimal

Given a `Decimal` number in python how can I find the number of digits past the decimal point?

```
assert digits(Decimal('1.2345')) == 4
assert digits(Decimal('1000'))   == 0
assert digits(Decimal('1.00'))   == 2
assert digits(Decimal('1E+5'))   == 0
assert digits(Decimal('1.2E+5')) == 0
```

Comment: What if it have infinite digits after decimal point? such as 0.3333...

Comment: I'm not sure infinite digits after a decimal point is possible with the Decimal class.

Comment: Decimal(1) / 3 ==
Decimal('0.3333333333333333333333333333'). There will be many digits but that does not mean anything.,

Comment: I thought the precision limit would force the issue, is that not true?

Comment: OK, even if not the infinite case, Decimal(1.2) will result in
Decimal('1.1999999999999999555910790149937383830547332763671875')

Comment: I don't think that is true after reading the Decimal specifications.

Comment: Just type `from decimal import Decimal; Decimal(1.2)` in python console, it will print Decimal('1.1999999999999999555910790149937383830547332763671875')

Comment: The default precision for a Decimal is 28 digits. It is user alterable, but it is not infinite.

Comment: I find out my mistake, I passed a double as parameter to Decimal, pass a string to it have no such problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After a bit of experimentation, this seems to work correctly:

```
def digits(n):
    return max(0,-n.as_tuple().exponent)
```

Comment: What about `NaN`, `+Infinity`, `-Infinity`, subnormal decimals?

Comment: `NaN`, `+Infinity`, `-Infinity` and other special values raise an exception. This wasn't by design, but it makes sense as the number of fractional digits is undefined in these cases.

Comment: [subnormal value has an integer exponent](http://ideone.com/4uY27H). It seems your method works as is with subnormal values. To be consistent with the `decimal` module, you could return zero on TypeError (for NaN, etc) depending on how you use the result later. btw, this should be the accepted answer (the tick on the left).

Answer (score 2):

I'll just outline a possible algorithm, assuming you start with a string.

- Starting from the left, find decimal point.  Count digits between it and either an `'E'` or the end of the string.  If there is no decimal point, the count is zero.
- Parse out the value following `'E'` and convert to integer.  If there is no `'E'`, that's zero.
- Subtract the second from the first of the two above values; the maximum of that and zero is the result.  So `'2E-2'` would have two decimal places, `'1.2E+5'` would have none, and the rather silly `'0.02E2'` would have none.
- As a degenerate case, zero itself would probably have zero decimal positions.  As for infinity and any other special values, I don't have a strong opinion whether that's zero decimal places or not.

Comment: Seems like this would work, but it feels "hacky". Also, I am starting with Decimal not a string, so I would have to convert it to a string just to count the digits.

Comment: A legitimate point.  I'm not an expert with the `Decimal` API, but my fear is that any evaluation you might do on the object itself would be about as time-expensive as just converting to string and then counting digits... and far more labor-expensive up front.

Comment: Also, I think this algorithm doesn't work for '1.2E+5'. Wouldn't we get, 5-1 = 4 or am I misunderstanding something?

Comment: You got it backwards. It would be 1 - 5 = -4. You should add one more step to the algorithm: if the answer is negative, return 0.

Comment: @morningstar Thank you, fixed final step.